# What's the meaning of "put someone on one's heels"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Get graphics working on tables, charts, the whole nine yards. Janine!
>
> What's the angle, five words?
>
> Far left of center.
>
> That's four.
>
> Very far left of center.
>
> **Enough to put Walker on his heels?**
>
> f*ck his heels.
>
> This will put him on his ass.

*from season 1 episode 1, House of Cards*

What's the meaning of "put someone on one's heels"?

Comment: Putting an adversary "on his heels" means "putting him on the defensive", i.e. he's more likely to take a backward step than to advance, and you can take the initiative.  It's good, but not as decisive as "putting him on his ass".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*'To put someone on their heels'* is a variation on *'rock someone back on their heels'*.

From the Oxford online Dictionary site (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set-or-rock-someone-back-on-their-heels):

> set (or rock) someone back on their heels
>   Definition of set or rock someone back on their heels in English:
>   Astonish or disconcert someone:
>   *'She said something that rocked me back on my heels'. 'Then, just as the team seemed to be establishing a foothold, two interceptions set them back on their heels'.  'A tremendous drive set them back on their heels, forcing them to concede a penalty.' 'They counter attack from deep in their own defence and our forwards should have been tackling them with a ferocity that would have disrupted them and rocked them back on their heels near their own lines.'*

Essentially it describes a physical shock that almost knocks someone backward, but they manage to retain their balance while pivoting on the heels of their shoes.  The next stage would be, *'To knock someone on their back (or whatever local expression applies to buttocks).'*

Comment: Yes, it's as if the individual has been struck in the jaw and has *almost* fallen over backwards.

Answer (score 3):

According to *[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/set-back-on-one-s-heels)*, to set someone on their heels is to put them in:

> Surprise, shock, or disconcert, as in The news of their divorce set us back on our heels. This idiom, with its graphic image of someone being pushed back, dates from the first half of the 1900s.